# In Rails, How do you render straight to xml without builder/layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought this was possible in the past, but apparently "now" this:

```
render xml: JSON.parse(results.to_json).to_xml
```

Errors out with:

```
Missing template account_requests/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

Sometimes I have a very light weight object, and to me (imo), it'd just be less complex to dump it straight from the controller.

Is this still possible in Rails 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `render inline: "xml.p {'Horrid coding practice!'}", type: :builder`

If you use the :xml option, render will automatically call to_xml for you.

```
render xml: JSON.parse(results.to_json)
```

Comment: There may be religious reasons why someone would condemn this practice, but I don't see it as a coding issue. :D I was hoping there was just a simple "direct" approach to getting xml out (for testing web services). In the end these will all be done with json. Thanks @zolter, I'll deal with building a builder layout.